# How to display a text from a file on a WizardPage

Tags: java, file, eclipse-plugin

I've been trying to read a text from a file and display it on my WizardPage. 
It cannot be displayed but when I type the Text manually it shows the string.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Read_file {

// create ArrayList to store the information of a wizardPage
public List<Inventory> invItem = new ArrayList<>();

public read_file(String file_name) {

    try {
        // create a Buffered Reader object instance with a FileReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));

        // read the first line from the text file
        String fileRead = br.readLine();

        // loop until all lines are read
        while (fileRead != null) {

            // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
            // each line of
            // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
            String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(":");

            // assume file is made correctly
            // and make temporary variables for the three types of data
            String Name = tokenize[0];
            String Next = tokenize[1];
            String Story = tokenize[2];

            // creat temporary instance of Inventory object
            // and load with three data values
            Inventory tempObj = new Inventory(Name, Next, Story);

            // add to array list
            invItem.add(tempObj);

            // read next line before looping
            // if end of file reached
            fileRead = br.readLine();
        }

        // close file stream
        br.close();
    }

    // handle exceptions
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

This is my Wizard :

```
   public class Wizard_main extends Wizard {
   Page first;
   Page third;
   end End;
   Read_file read=new Read_file("wizard.txt");

   String story1=read.invItem.get(0).Story; // **this string cannot be displayed** 

   String story2="After a couple of hours, Jack woke up..."; //this one 
   works fine

    public void addPages(){ 
    first= new Page("S1",story1);
    third=new Page("S2",story2);
    End= new end("END");

    first.setNextPage("S2", "S3");
    third.setNextPage("S2", "S1");
    addPage(First);
    addPage(Third);
    addPage(End);


}

@Override
public boolean performFinish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}}
```

I'm having "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" when I try to display a text from a file on my WizardPage.

```
 Stack trace : !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
 !STACK 0
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0         
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)          
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

Note: The Text is properly displayed while using System.out.println() in another class

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? Do you get an exception? Note: Please try and stick to the Java naming conventions - variables names start with a lower case character. Not following the conventions makes it much harder for other people to read your code and confuses the Stack Overflow code formatter.

Comment: Oh sorry I get java.lang.NullPointerException and thank you for your tips about variables names. I'm still beginner at programming

Comment: Edit your question and show us the stack trace and indicate where the error line is in your code.

Comment: That stack trace is a problem in the Eclipse Oomph installer code and is not related to your wizard at all. What happens when you try and open your wizard? Most likely it is just not finding the file because `"wizard.txt"` specifies that the file is in the current working directory which is **not** the directory containing your wizard code.

Comment: It is true, it says that the file does not exist. But with another normal class I do not have this problem. "wizard.txt" is located in the package

Comment: The current directory varies depending on how you run things. With an Eclipse plugin you should **never** rely on the current directory. If you intend the text file to be part of the plugin you will need to use the Eclipse `FileLocator` API to find it.

Comment: @greg-449 actually it was really simple. you just need to change the location of the file where the activator class is located. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: That isn't going to work when you package the plugin in a jar - only the FileLocator APIs work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution which I used is as following :

```
 private String getJsonFilePath(String fileName) {

    String filePath = "";
    // Reading file within the plugin
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.eclipseplugin.sics");
    // Get the wizard file from the plugin location.
    URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("lib/" + fileName + ".json");
    try {
        filePath = FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).getPath().substring(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filePath;
}
```

This is how FileLocator should be used.